# Installing Linux on Mac OS X Not Finding Disk Partition

Tags: ubuntu, mount, osx, partition, system-installation

I am trying to install Linux (specifically Ubuntu 16.04) on my Mac OS X 10.13.3. I followed the instructions [here](https://www.lifewire.com/dual-boot-linux-and-mac-os-4125733). I created a USB installer with UNetbootin, installed rEFInd, created a 124 gb partition of my hard drive and even booted ubuntu successfully from the USB drive. However, when I try to install, I get the message "You need at least 8.6 GB disk space to install ubuntu. This computer has only 8.1 GB".

When I look under the Ubuntu system preferences, it indeed thinks the hard drive is only 8.1 GB (size of the USB stick). Furthermore, when I do `df -h` at `/dev/sda*`, they all show 8gb. So, I suspect Ubuntu does not see the partitioned hard drive I have created.

How do I correct the problem so that Ubuntu can see the partitions I have created on the Mac and allow me to continue the installation?

Comment: What is the output of `lsblk`? It should show all block devices

Comment: `df` is used to show mounted filesystems, so it's not what you need. You can use `cfdisk /dev/sda` to confirm your partitions; You should see your MacOS, EFI, and Linux (perhaps FAT per instructions) partitions.

Comment: Did anyone ever solve this? Having the same problem... @user1413793